# How to fix the multiple error bar issue of ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

```
ggplot(data)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(x=treatment, y=deg), stat = "identity", 
           width=0.4, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=treatment, ymin=deg, ymax=deg+se), 
                width=0.2, position=position_dodge(width=1))
```

[image]

I can't do the error bars right and as you can see multiple error bars are coming. I don't know what is going on here. its different treatment vs decomposition rate

Comment: Could you upload some data? or we cannot locate where the problem is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)